mern stack: data is available in the console but not rendering in the UI
mern stack: data is available in the console but not rendering in the UI.
I fetched the data in the context api
This below is from the api
router.get('/transactions', async(req, res) => {
  const user_id = req.user

  const data = await transactionSchema.findOne({user_id})
  res.status(200).json({data})
  
})

This is my context api code from the frontend below
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:4000/transaction/transactions',{
        method: 'GET',
          headers:{
            'AUthorization': `${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application.json',
          },
      }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
          
      if(localStorage.getItem('token')){
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/transaction/get/:accNo', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers:{
            'AUthorization': `${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application.json',
          },
        
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((user) => setTransaction(user));
      }
      
    }
    fetchData()
},[])

This is the rendering page where I want the data to display in the frontend
import { useContext } from "react"
import { TransactionContext } from "../contextApi/AuthContext";


const TransactionDetails = () => {

const {datas} = useContext(TransactionContext)

if(datas){
  console.log(datas.data);
  }

  if(!datas){
    return <p>Loading...</p>
    }

    


     return (
    <div style={{marginTop: "150px"}}>
      <p>Data: {datas._id}</p>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default TransactionDetails


Hi, you'll need to share your code - preferably as a [mre] - We can't help much without that.

Yup. Mern stack would be anything and it not showing on the front-end could be for any reason.
